# How to find $\theta$ ??

Tags: trigonometry

If $0\leq\theta\leq360$, and:
$$\tan \theta=2+\sqrt{3}$$
 Where $\theta$ is in degrees .
How to find $\theta$  (without using a calculator) ? Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: There are two angles in the given interval with this property.

Comment: @Peter How do i find them ? How come there are two angles ?

Comment: @Shona the tangent-function has period $180°$. See my answer how we can proof that $tan(75°)=2+\sqrt{3}$. However, I have no idea how to get the angle without a calculator.

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

$$2+\sqrt3=\tan(45^\circ+y)=\dfrac{1+\tan y}{1-\tan y}$$

$$\iff\tan y=\dfrac{2+\sqrt3-1}{2+\sqrt3+1}=\dfrac1{\sqrt3}=\tan ?^\circ$$

Comment: It gives $30^\circ$ . Any angle of tan can ba found by using this method ?

Comment: @Shona, Which are related to the known angles

Comment: @Shona, See also my other answer

Answer (score 6):

Double the angle "to see", and get

$$\tan(2\theta)=\frac{2(2+\sqrt3)}{1-(2+\sqrt3)^2}=-\frac1{\sqrt3}=-\tan(30°).$$

Then $\theta$ must be one of $75°,165°,255°,345°$, of which two angles must be rejected (they were introduced by the doubling). A quick look at the trigonometric circle shows that the solutions belong to the first or third quadrant,

$$75°,255°.$$

---

Actually, this is a general and systematic approach: it will work for any tangent of a rational number of half-turns, $$\theta=\frac pq180°.$$

You can try all integers $q$ in turn and compute $\tan(q\theta)$ by successive applications of the addition formula, until you get to $\tan(p180°)=0$ (but you can stop earlier if you get to a known value).

For example, from

$$\tan(\theta)=\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}$$ you get

$$\begin{align}\tan(2\theta)&=(\sqrt5+2)\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}},\\
\tan(3\theta)&=-\frac14(\sqrt5+1)(\sqrt5+3)\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}},\\
\tan(4\theta)&=-\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}},\\
\tan(5\theta)&=0.\end{align}$$

Comment: By comparing $2\theta=150^\circ$ and it gives the answer .right ?

Comment: @Shona: or $2\theta=3\cdot180°-30°=510°$.

Comment: how you got $$\begin{align}\tan(2\theta)&=(5+\sqrt2)\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}},\\
\tan(3\theta)&=-\frac14(\sqrt5+1)(\sqrt5+3)\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}},\\
\tan(4\theta)&=-\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}},\\
\tan(5\theta)&=0.\end{align}$$

Comment: Successive applications of the addition formula with $2\theta=\theta+\theta,3\theta=2\theta+\theta,\cdots$. Tedious, but bulletproof.

Comment: It gives $$\begin{align}\tan(2\theta)&=(2+\sqrt5)\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}},\end{align}$$ 2 in place of 5 and 5 in place of 2 after solving

Comment: because i dont have the edit privillege so i can not edit

Comment: here in this xample  $5\theta=0$ i.e. $\theta=0$ but $$\tan(0) is not equal to \sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: $5\theta=k180°$.

Comment: i.e. $\theta=k36^\circ$ would be the generalised value for $\theta$

Comment: For every k Except k = 0

Comment: No, not every $k$. There are other exceptions.

Comment: Then how would one know that the value we are choosing is an exception ?

Comment: @Shona: I have no good answer at the moment.

Comment: its ok whenever you come to know  you can tell . Thanks for helping so much ☺

Answer (score 3):

The given tangent is not one of the well-known values, so you need to look for a combination of known values, probably by the angle addition/subtraction formula.

The term $\sqrt3$ hints you to look for the angle $60°$. So try

$$\tan(\theta-60°)=\frac{\tan(\theta)-\tan(60°)}{1+\tan(\theta)\tan(60°)}=\frac{2+\sqrt3-\sqrt3}{1+(2+\sqrt3)\sqrt3}=\frac1{2+\sqrt3}.$$

Bingo, you see that this is the inverse of the given $\tan(\theta)$, or $\cot(\theta)=\tan(90°-\theta)$. Then

$$\theta-60°=90°-\theta,$$ or

$$\theta=75°.$$
Note that
$$\theta=75°+180°=255°$$ is also a solution.

Comment: Yes i was also thinking of using $60^\circ$ but didnt know how to use . Thank you for helping 

Comment: @Shona: see my other answer, even simpler but more a rabbit pulled from a hat.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\tan(75°)=\tan(30°+45°)=\frac{\tan(30°)+\tan(45)°}{1-\tan(30°)\tan(45°)}=$$ $$\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}+1}{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}+3}{3-\sqrt{3}}
=\frac{(3+\sqrt{3})(3+\sqrt{3})}{9-3}=\frac{12+6\sqrt{3}}{6}=2+\sqrt{3}$$

So, one solution is $75°$ . The other is $75°+180°=255°$

Comment: How do we know that we had to  take $30^\circ$ and $45^\circ$

Comment: I admit, that I have no idea yet. But at least we can show that $75°$ does the job (without a calculator)

Comment: @Shona it is a special case. Just like if the number was 1 then you take $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: @Peter see the other answers here

Comment: @ritwik sinha see the answers here.

Comment: @Shona thanks, Great answer by Yves Daoust., I didn't know that.

Comment: @ritwik sinha you are welcome ☺

Answer (score 1):

$$\sec2A+\tan2A=\dfrac{1+\sin2A}{\cos2A}=\tan\left(45^\circ+A\right)$$

Here $A=30^\circ$

Comment: How come $$\dfrac{1+\sin2A}{\cos2A}=\tan\left(45^\circ+A\right)$$
?

Comment: @Shona,  Use https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Weierstrass_Substitution

Comment: How A equals $30^\circ$  ?

Comment: @Shona, $$2=\sec60^\circ,\sqrt3=\tan60^\circ$$

Comment: Oh yes thank you for helping ☺